# Expand div on text click for five separate DIVs

Tags: jquery, html

I have a construction like this:

```
<h3>Text</h3>
<p>(text from CSS)</p>
<div>hidden content goes here</div>
```

And it goes five times (five headings and five DIVs).

In CSS, I have defined :after for classes "expanded" and "collapsed" (expand and collapse CONTENT attributes, because when I click on paragraph, text is expanding and collapsing when I click again). So I have "expand" text to click when content is collapsed and "collapse" when expanded.

The problem is, the script I'm using supports only one DIV. When I do the same trick for five DIVs, I have a problem, because all, five DIVs are expanding/collapsing at one time.

I'm using this code near BODY closing tag:

```
$('.expand').simpleexpand();
```

And this script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redhotsly/simple-expand/master/src/simple-expand.min.js

Could anyone explain me what I need to do so it will work separately for those DIVs?

Also, I'm using a Fullpage.js script and it destroys the page scrolling (text goes below the section, to the next slide, like code can't read the section should have a fluid height...).

Thanks for any help.

Edit:
Okay, I've finally figured it out. Content should be placed in other, separate div:

```
<h3>text</h3>
<div>
<p>(text from CSS)</p>
<div>hidden content</div>
</div>
```

But I still have the problem, that expanded text is making HEIGHT of section bigger and it "eats" the rest of the content (**scrollbar isn't showing and overflow is hiding**).

Image: http://take.ms/f2oxa

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your expand library once per element:

```
$('.expand').each(function() {
    $(this).simpleexpand();
});
```